# In-App purchase for widget Android Billing Version 3

Tags: android, android-widget, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am looking to restrict access to a new widget I have added to one of my Android apps, so that it is available as an In-App purchase.
Is there a way to check to see if the widget as been purchased and if not the stop the user from being able to use it?

I can easily query items in Activity classes but in the AppWidgetProvider I am struggling to get there.

If it is possible, could you provide either a link or some sample code to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since there was no help I managed to find a work around myself ;)

Incase anyone else wants to know :-

When the In-app product is purchased I add a unique identifier to the shared preferences and recall it when it tries to create the widget.

Comment: I'm also interested in doing something like that. Can you explain a little bit deeper how use in-app purchase just for the widget?

Comment: Hi @Daniele, sorry it has been a long time since I have done anything with this and the Android Billing System has changed a lot in the past 3 years so wouldn't be able to give you a confident answer :( I would suggest starting a new thread asking the question and hopefully someone else would be able to help.